# Ruby regex to remove / from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I currently have a string to remove spaces from strings, however I now need to remove forward slashes from the string too. I'm not very good with regexes and could use some help thanks. This is the current regex I have: `gsub(/\s+/, "")` how do I modify this to remove / ? I've played around in the console and can't seem to get it.

Comment: http://rubular.com. You need to escape the slash. `/[\s\/]+/`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. so something like this? gsub(/\s+ \/, ""). woops sorry you showed some code. I'll try that out thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks very much. Go ahead and answer if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the forward slash because it's a special character. Something like this:

```
s = "This   is a line / string"
s.gsub(/[\s\/]/, '') # => "Thisisalinestring"
```